# Can't change xubuntu 13.04 background

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background

I've just installed xubuntu 13.04 and when i start xfdesktop-settings i can't add nor change background (note I have 2 screen)

[image]

I have also tried "set as background" option in the right click menu, but nothing happened.
Can someone explain me where is the problem?